# How to Write excel file from R to xlsx

Tags: r, openxlsx

I am writing my output to xlsx via below code.many times getting error after restarting R studio also.Is there any permanent solution to avoid error.

Error :- First argument must be a Workbook.

```
require(openxlsx)
library(xlsx)

OUT <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(OUT,"Sheet1", tabColour = "orange")
addWorksheet(OUT,"Sheet2", tabColour = "orange")
```

any suggestions would be helpful.

No excel file is there in working directory too.

Comment: You open the `xlsx` package after opening the `openxlsx` package. R by default uses whichever package gets opened later. It looks like you want to use the `openxlsx` version of `addWorksheet` and not the `xlsx` version.

Comment: you can show the errors of your session

Comment: ```Error in addWorksheet(OUT, "Sheet2", tabColour = "green") : 
  First argument must be a Workbook.```

Comment: Remove `library(xlsx)` and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much Phil it is working fine now ,after not installing ```library(xlsx)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
require(openxlsx)
library(xlsx)
```

you may have seen the message

```
Attaching package: ‘xlsx’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:openxlsx’:
    createWorkbook, loadWorkbook, read.xlsx, saveWorkbook, write.xlsx
```

and, as you now know, this masking caused your problem.  You can avoid this by not using the `xlsx` package, but that is not the only option.  Alternatively you can tell R explicitly that you want to use `createWorkbook` and `addWorksheet` from the `openxlsx` package with:

```
OUT <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()

openxlsx::addWorksheet(OUT, "Sheet1", tabColour = "orange")
openxlsx::addWorksheet(OUT, "Sheet2", tabColour = "orange")
```